# on Heroku how can I get the current release number of my app

Tags: python, heroku

I'd like to display the release number on a page on my site, to show the current heroku release.

My thoughts are to get it and store it in an environment variable, however I don't know how to access the release number on deployment.

Can anyone tell me how I might do this?

I've read:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase

and read:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases

I'm wondering if it's even possible or if I'd have to do it locally as part of a script incrementing the current version number and adding that as an environment variable. Just thought there might be a built in version

Comment: Heroku doesn't inject that into the app by default (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28657555/3001761 for how you can get the env vars that are set). You could maybe write a script to get the value from `heroku releases` data and `heroku config:set` it, but it looks like setting an env var increments the release :/

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7917523/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe well yes and no, the answers in that one are Ruby specific. I'm not aruby dev. Seems the answer is to  create a script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable the `runtime-dyno-metadata` lab to inject this metadata into your applications' environment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

just `heroku labs:enable runtime-dyno-metadata -a <app name>`, you'll need to generate a new release, either by deploying new code, or updating your config vars.

Once you've done this, you'll have access to `HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION` in the env.

Comment: It's annoying that you have to do that, but it works ... so not as annoying as writing my own script.